# Re-installing Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bios, raid, intel-rst

I just updated the BIOS on my MSI motherboard to the latest version without really thinking about the repercussions. I had the BIOS version of Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology Driver installed on my pc, and on the RAID 0 array that the program had created I have my OS installed. After updating my BIOS I seem to have deleted the RAID driver, and so my PC cannot boot.

I could go ahead and attempt to re-install the drivers, or I could find a spare drive with windows on it and try to recover my data, or any manor of other method to attempt to access my files, however I do not want to rush into anything in case I accidentally screw things up and lose all of my data. Because of this I thought it would be best if I asked the experts what the safest option would be.

All that I want to do is place my three drives back into RAID 0 format, without losing anything.

Worst comes to worst, it wouldn't be the first time I had completely wiped my drives and started again.

Comment: Be sure your firmware settings are correct, your driver wasn't deleted, but your settings likely were restore to their defaults.

Comment: What Ramhound said. Your mass storage setting was most likely set to the default value AHCI. Setting it to RAID should get your Windows to boot again.